# GraphQL HotChocolate Adding PaginationAmountType converts my int's to PaginationAmmount

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

when i add the PaginationAmmountType to set the max records per page all of my models int variables get turrned into PaginatioAmount

```
services.AddGraphQL(SchemaBuilder.New()
                .AddType(new PaginationAmountType(100))
                .AddQueryType<Query>()
                .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                .AddAuthorizeDirectiveType()
            );
```

this is how it looks without the PaginationAmountType

[image]

and then this is what it changes to when i add the PaginationAmountType

[image]

How can i resolve this or what exactly am i doing wrong i need to specify a max amount of records per page but this method of doing so is messing up my models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `PaginationAmount` is also based on `IntType`. The schema discovers the `PaginationType` and binds it to the `int` type

Can you try this:

```
services.AddGraphQL(SchemaBuilder.New()
                .AddQueryType<Query>()
                .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                .AddAuthorizeDirectiveType()
                .AddType(new IntType())
                .AddType(new PaginationAmountType(100))
            );
```

Btw. we released Version 11. It brings a lot on new features and improvements. We also dropped the PaginationAmountType completely.

Check out the migration Guide:
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/migrate-from-10-to-11/

Comment: Thank you i had tried going up to version 11 and saw it was removed but i couldn't find what had replaced it thank you for the link!

Comment: i have upgraded to version 11 and changed to using AddGraphQLServer in place of AddGraphQL and app.UseRouting();
            app.UseRouting().UsePlayground();
            app.UseEndpoints(x => x.MapGraphQL()); in place of UseGraphQL but now when i run my project i am getting a server cannot be reached in playground and "error": "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Ah sorry i see in the docks "we dropped support for Playground and GraphiQL and have added our own GraphQL IDE Banana Cake Pop"

Comment: you can access the server under "/graphql" by default. If you would like to map it to the root you can do app.UseEndpoints(x => x.MapGraphQL("/"))

Comment: if you do this in the browser BananaCakePop shows up :) just do not use Safari :D